# How to access actual text content from HTML Date input

Tags: javascript, angular, date, html-input

I am using a native HTML Date input component like below in Angular -

```html
 <input #dateField id="dateField" type="date">
```

```js
@ViewChild("dateField") el: ElementRef;

onClick() {
  console.log(this.el.nativeElement.shadowRoot);
}
```

It rendered the date based on the operating system locale of the user like below -

[image]

However, whenever I try to access the value from this field, it always returns the value in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

I want to access the actual string value which is getting displayed on the UI as per user locale like '16-Sep-2021'. Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried properties such as innerHTML, textContent, innerText, outerText but none of them is returning the actual displayed value.

Also, is it possible to access the locale information in which it is showing this date value? Even if the default placeholder text -

[image]

I am also not able to access the `shadowRoot` property on this element, it always returns me null.

Also, this is not specific with Angular, even if normal Javascript it gives same result.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specific benefit you’d get from extracting a locale-specific date format as opposed to something more standardized? Usually, this question is asked in the reverse to ensure the consistency of the data for processing.

Comment: @esqew, thanks for your response. Actually, we are trying to fix an issue when the user has different setup of locales between the Operating System and the Browser. This date field takes input in OS format but when we want to display it in a label text format through Angular date pipe we cannot access the OS locale and displays it into Browser locale and caused the mismatch. So, if we can somehow access the OS locale, we can format the date into that same format while displaying it within text content.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you're looking for. You can only retrieve the value in one of the following formats:

1. `value` will return the date in `yyyy-mm-dd`.
2. `valueAsNumber` will return the date in timestap
3. `valueAsDate` will return the date in JavaScript Date format.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, we have already tried these functions, but they also return values irrespective of any locale information.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can use,

> fromDate

package to convert date into output like you wanted, here is the snippet just copy and paste at required place and you will be able to see the date format you wanted:

```
//add this
import { formatDate } from "@angular/common";

//format it
const format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
const myDate = '2019-sep-16';
const locale = 'en-US';
const formattedDate = formatDate(myDate, format, locale);
console.log(formattedDate)//16/09/2019
```

Hope this will help :-p